# cumulative frequency array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, cumulative-frequency

I've got an array of integers and i was wondering how you would code for a cumulative frequency array. should i use a for loop or is there a quicker way.

e.g given integers:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
the new array would print: 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36
thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

one way, very inefficient:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use List::Util qw/sum/;

    my @arr = (1..10);
    my @newarr;

for my $i (0..$#arr) {
    $newarr[$i] = sum(@arr[0..$i]) 
}
```

looping and summing is much better:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = (1..10);
my @newarr;
my $mid;

for my $i (0..$#arr) {
  $mid += $arr[$i];
  push(@newarr,$mid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `map` instead of `foreach ... push`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my @arr = 1..10;
my $sum;
my @newarr = map { $sum += $_ } @arr;
print "@newarr\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easily done in a single `for` loop

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = 1 .. 8;

my @cumulative = $data[0];
push @cumulative, $cumulative[-1] + $_ for @data[1..$#data];

print "@cumulative\n";
```

**output**

```
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36
```